# Flutter Container on top of rows

Tags: flutter, dart

I made a bunch of rows. Now I want a Container on top of these rows. How can I do this. I tried it with the stack widget ,but it just stacked everything on top of each other and I had no control over the positioning.

How can I draw a Container on top of a bunch of rows.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the below code, though your asking is little bit confusing. You need to use `Positioned` and set some value at top and left.

```
Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      Positioned(
        top:0 ,
        left: 0,
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      Positioned(
        top:100 ,
        left: 0,
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Row(),
          ),
        ),
      Positioned(
        top:200 ,
        left: 0,
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Row(),
          ),
        ),
      Positioned(
        top:300 ,
        left: 0,
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Row(),
          ),
        ),
    ],
  ),
)
```